# typing for passing React context as prop

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-context

I need to pass context as a prop to a component. I know this sounds anti-pattern but the component receiving the context as a prop is deeply nested and generic. It doesn't know which context to use so therefore context must be passed as a prop. This component does not care what the type of context is as long as it implements some required fields.

The component definition is:

```
interface RequiredFilterContext { ... };

interface Props<C extends RequiredFilterContext> { 
 context: React.Context<C>;
}

const Filters = <C>({context}: Props) => { ... };
```

The parent component is:

```
interface ParentContext extends RequiredFilterContext { ... };

const parentContext = React.createContext({} as ParentContext);

const Parent = () => {
 return <Filters context={parentContext} />
};
```

In the `<Filters>` component context can be used with correct type inference.

However a type error in the `<Parent>` component:

> Type  Context  is not assignable to type
> Context
> The types of  Provider.propTypes  are incompatible between these types.

Comment: _"I need to pass context as a prop to a component"_... I cannot think of a situation where that would **ever** be required.

Comment: It's a component that filters, sorts and searches data. It needs to be reusable. Depending on where it's used the shape of the data can be different. This data is the displayed in a table. The table can't be a child of the filter component. But the filter component needs to manipulate the data. The only work around I can think of is having two context providers - one of which is only the RequiredFilterContext for the Filter component to consume. I'd prefer to keep at a single context though if possible.

Comment: You seem to be missing `Props<C>`

Comment: What properties of the context are you intending on using in your `Filters` component? Having the context value type be generic will make using `Provider` difficult but perhaps you're not using that anyway

Comment: `Props<C>` was a typo in the contrived example I used. The properties I intend to use are `page` and `setData`. I guess I will just have to use two context providers.

Comment: Those are context value properties. What do you intend to use from the context itself? The only useful available properties are `Provider` and `Consumer`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two main integration points...

1. In order to satisfy the `C extends RequiredFilterContext` on `Props`, you will need to add or move the same condition to your `Filters` generic type
2. You're missing the generic type on `Props` in your function signature

I would also rename the prop to be Pascal-cased within `Filter` to adhere to React conventions

```tsx
import type { Context } from 'react';

interface RequiredFilterContext { ... };

interface Props<C> { // the extends isn't really required here
  context: Context<C>;
}

const Filters = <C extends RequiredFilterContext>({
  context: FilterContext,
}: Props<C>) => (
  <FilterContext.Consumer children={(context) => ( ... )} /> // just an example
);
```